# The mean of a running maximum

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes

Suppose $$ is a one-dimensional standard Brownian motion defined on some probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal F, P)$ and let $():=\exp\{()−\frac{1}{2}−\frac{1}{+1}\}$ for $\ge 0$. Note that $(\infty):=\limsup_{t\to\infty}()=0$ a.s. because $\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{()}{}=0$ a.s.

My question is: How to show that $E[\sup_{0\le t\le \infty}()]=\infty$? Many thanks. (I posed this question in  stackexchange earlier today. Not sure if this is the right place to ask this question.)

Many thanks.

Comment: Can we ignore the $1/(t+1)$?

Comment: The supremum of a Brownian motion with drift -1/2 is distributed as an exponential random variable of mean 1.

Answer (score 3):

This seems to me a standard exercice in a probability course: Ignore the $1/(t+1)$ term as $X(t)\geq e^{-1}\exp(W(t)-t/2)$. The term $M_t:=\exp(W(t)-t/2)$ is well known to be a martingale so $\mathbb{E}(M_t)=1$ for all $t$. If $\mathbb{E}(\sup_{0\leq t\leq \infty}X_t)<\infty$ then by dominated convergence $$1=\mathbb{E}(M_t)\rightarrow_{t\rightarrow \infty} \mathbb{E}(M_\infty)=0$$

Comment: Great! Many thanks.